# How to convert TIFF to PDF using Ghostscript

Tags: php, pdf, tiff, ghostscript

How can I convert TIFF to PDF using Ghostscript?

I tried to use the code below but it not working:

**Snippet**

```
$input_file_tif='test.pdf';
$input_file_orig_name='1234.tiff';
$gs_command = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=tiffg3 -r300x300 \
                  -sOutputFile='".$input_file_tif."".$input_file_orig_name."' ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript doesn't support TIFF as an input, so you can't immediately use it to turn a TIFF file into a PDF. You might be better to use an image editing application such as ImageMagick.

For anyone who wishes to persist, it is possible to read a TIFF file by writing a PostScript program, which Ghostscript is able to run (because it is a PostScript interpreter). See this question on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211428/conversion-tif-to-pdf-ghostscript

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason for using Ghostscript?

If you have gs installed, you very probably also have Image Magick's `convert` command. [This article](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23225) discusses some aspects of the quality factor and how to maintain a reasonable output size.

Also consider the possibility that, if the input file is technical (i.e. drawings) you might consider tracing the input and doing a conversion to a real vector image, which would create a much smaller PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I Convert the Tiff file to Pdf File by use Imagick

code :

$document = new Imagick(test.tiff);

$document->setImageFormat("pdf");

$document->writeImages("test.pdf", true);